# Select the most-recent element in one column based on the time filter in DAX

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I have the following table:

| ID | Status | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Open | 12/01/2023 |
| 1 | Closed | 13/01/2023 |
| 1 | Open | 14/01/2023 |
| 2 | Closed | 14/01/2023 |
| 2 | Open | 15/01/2023 |
| 3 | Open | 18/01/2023 |

I would like to COUNT how many IDs with Open Status as the most-recent status. For example, if I apply no filter for Date (selecting all dates), my desired result would be:

| ID | Status | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Open | 15/01/2023 |
| 2 | Open | 15/01/2023 |
| 3 | Open | 18/01/2023 |

==> 3 IDs with the most-recent Status as Open

If I filter Date from 12/01/2023 to 14/01/2023, it should be:

| ID | Status | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Open | 14/01/2023 |

==> 1 ID

I have tried the following measure in an attempt to get the most-recent status of each ID (and their dates) based on the the time filter applied.

```
status = CALCULATE(
    VALUES('Table'[Status]),
    FILTER(ALL('Table'[Date]), 'Table'[Date] = MAX('Table'[Date]))
)
```

However, still struggling to Count the number of IDs for a specific status.

Comment: What result did you get when you ran your attempt? Does your attempt get the most-recent status and you're struggling to count them, or does your attempt not work?

Comment: @B.Griffin Hi, thanks for asking. It works as follows:
- Create a table visual containing: ID, Measure_Status (it shows the latest status, yes) 
- when i put into that visual another field "Count of ID" with filter on Measure Status to filter out Open ==> the Count of ID works as expected.
However, what I expect is to create a Measure, which can give me that Count only without setting up the the table visual as above